# Jekyll recognizes collection (and metadata) but does not generate html output

Tags: jekyll

Among the many collections I have built (and that run fine) with my Jekyll site, my latest one is giving me output trouble. It's a collection for calendar events.

Here is the `config.yml`:

`collections:
  calendar-events:
    output: true
    permalink: /events/:slug
    _hide_content: false`

Here are the markdown files in their [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f46GA.png)

The events markdown files carry a `published:true` value

Here is an [index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdJvq.png) asking for a list of urls for that collection, which returns the data correctly (both test files have the same title).

However, when I click one of these urls (again, the url being generated by the system), I get a "not found" error. Upon inspection of the `_site` folder, I see that no html files have been created based off the collection's markdown files, *even though* the index page is telling me that Jekyll is aware of them and sees their metadata.

This is the only collection I have running that gives me this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. There was just some kind of interference from whitespace in the markdown files (I still don't know exactly *how*. There were no trailing spaces). Starting over from scratch with a new markdown file fixed the problem.